# Property cannot be assigned to undefined in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to plot a histogram using angular. The jsfiddle link below is for reference. I am trying to create a series object for histogram highchart in angular to match the one shown in the example. My current code gives me an error cannot set property name of undefined. This error occurs in the very first  assignment of the property in the for loop. Could some body tell me where am i going wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/x51b6pvs/52/

My code in angular

chartSeries: any[];

```
 this.results[0].data = [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];
  this.results[1].data = [4.5, 4, 5.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 5.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 5.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 5.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 5.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 5.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 5.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 5.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 5.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 5.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 6, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];
  this.results[2].data = [5.5, 6, 7.2, 5.1, 4.6, 7.9, 3.4, 7.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 7.4, 3, 3, 4, 7.4, 3.9, 5.5, 5.8, 5.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 7, 3.4, 8.1, 3, 6.1, 9.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];
  this.results[3].data = [4.5, 4, 5.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 5.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 5.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 5.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 5.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 5.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 5.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 5.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 5.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 7.8, 7.2, 3, 5.8, 5.6, 5.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 5.7, 6.3, 8.2, 2.8, 3, 5.8, 3, 2.8, 7.8, 8.8, 9.8, 4.6, 3, 8.4, 7.1, 8, 4.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];

 for(let i=0; i<this.results.length; i++)
    {
      var objHistogram:any;
        objHistogram.name="Histogram" + i;
        objHistogram.type="histogram";
        objHistogram.xAxis = 1;
        objHistogram.yAxis = 1;
        objHistogram.baseSeries="s"+i;
        objHistogram.zIndex=-1;

        var objectData:any;
        objectData.name="Data" + i;
        objectData.showInLegend= false;
        objectData.data=this.results[i].data;
        objectData.id="s"+i;

        this.chartSeries[2*i]=objHistogram;
        this.chartSeries[2*i+1]=objectData;
    }
```

Comment: `var objHistogram:any;`. you're declared it but didn't make any instance of it. if it should be empty object then do: `var objHistogram:any = {};`

Comment: The error is pretty damn clear, `objHistogram` is undefined, cause its never instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create the object in one declaration

```
// First, make the chartSeries an empty array
chartSeries: any[] = [];

for(let i=0; i<this.results.length; i++)
{
  let objHistogram = {
    name: "Histogram" + i,
    type: "histogram",
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: "s"+i,
    zIndex: -1
  }

  let objectData = {
    name: "Data" + i,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: this.results[i].data,
    id: "s"+i
  };

  // I dont know what you want the chartSeries array to look like, but you may as well just push onto the array.
  this.chartSeries.push(objHistogram);
  this.chartSeries.push(objectData);
}
```

Comment: The first two objects are getting populated but the following errors this.chartSeries[2*i]=objHistogram; The error is again undefined. the chartseries object

Comment: Sorry I had figured that out. I was too fast in posting in it. Thanks

Comment: Well I still answered the question, no?

Comment: Yes. Sorry i just meant the latter. Your answer definitely helped